# Converting code from PrototypeJS to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, prototype

I getting problem while converting PrototypeJS to jQuery. My prototypes JS is

```
function remove_invitation(target) {
  if (confirm('Delete this invitation?')) {
    $$('div#'+target+' input.hidden_delete')[0].setValue('1')
    Element.hide(target);  
   }
}
```

I have converted into jQuery as

```
function remove_chore(target) {
  if (confirm('Delete this chore?')) {
    $('div#'+target+'input.hidden_delete').first().val(1);
    // $('div#'+target).hide();
    $('div#'+target).css("display","none");
  }
}
```

Buts its not working as it was working PrototypeJS.

Comment: They're both JavaScript. It looks like you're trying to convert code originally written with the PrototypeJS library to work with jQuery instead. But that doesn't change the *language* you're using.

Comment: `$('#'+target).hide().find("input.hidden_delete:first").val(1);`

Comment: @AmritdeepDhungana Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Try to leave a space here:

```
$('div#'+target+' input.hidden_delete').first().val(1);
// --            ^ add space here
```

Also, because `id` is unique you can use `#` instead of `div#`:

```
function remove_chore(target) {
    if (confirm('Delete this chore?')) {
        $('#'+target+' input.hidden_delete').first().val(1);
        // $('div#'+target).hide();
        $('#'+target).css("display","none");
    }
}
```